# Trying to understand this highly abbreviated text

Tags: abbreviation

I know that asking for the translation is not allowed, but I'm asking for your help. I try to understand what is written in this car document but because of the many abbreviations, I'm almost stuck. For the things that I was abble to find the translation, I'll write it as the first answer.

1. ZU S.1:WAHLW.3.SITZREIHE,MAX.2 EINZELSITZE F.KINDER VON JEW. 15-36KG
2. SITZE GEPRUEFT NACH ECE-REGELUNG NR.44
3. ZU 18-20:L.43 00,H.BIS 1855 U.ZU G:BIS 1505
4. ZU F.1/F.2:+30 U.ZU 7.1-8.3:H.+50 B.ANH-BETR.
5. STATT REINF.AUCH XL
6. ZUL.GES-GEW.D.ZUGES MAX. 2680KG
7. WW.AHK LT.EGTG/ABE
8. M.VERTIEFT.BODENGRUPPE HINTEN.
9. M.AUFFAHRRAMPE IM FZ.-HECK.
10. M.GEAEND.ANBAULAGE VON MITTELSCHAL LDAEMFER.
11. BODENVER

[image]

Comment: Offtopic, unfortunately; this may help: M. = mit (with); jew. = jeweils (each); B.=bei ; ANH-BETR=Anhängerbetrieb (with trailer); ECE= Economic Commission Europe (type approval sign); EGTG= EG Typenggenehmigung (registered permission); ABE: Allgemeine Betriebserlaubnis (general type approval) AHK: Anhängerkupplung (trailer coupling)

Comment: @guidot very valuable your reply, and I thank you so much!

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? I can not think of a resource which might be easily consulted to resolve this bureaucracy riddle.

Comment: @Thomas because it's easier than answering it ;-) Sorry guys but sometimes I really wonder what is voted offtopic... As we can see this is a single source of concern. Not everyone can benefit from the answer but where else could this be asked?

Comment: @Thomas I guess the reason is that translations in general are not done here. However, I find GrafWampula's approach very elegant: expanding the abbreviations, which allows the OP to translate it themselves. I wonder, whether we can edit the question in a way that it doesn't ask for translation but expansion and reopen it again..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wahlweise 3. Sitzreihe, maximal 2 Einzelsitze für Kinder von jeweils 15-36 kg, Sitze geprüft nach ECE-Regelung Nr. 44.

Länge 4300 mm, Höhe bis 1855 mm

Masse des in Betrieb befindlichen Fahrzeugs bis zu 1505 kg Leergewicht.

F.1 Technisch zulässige Gesamtmasse = 1505 + 30 = 1535 kg

F.2 Im Zulassungsstaat zulässige Gesamtmasse = 1505 + 30 = 1535 kg

Höhe +50 bei Anhängerbetrieb

Statt Reinforced-Reifen auch XL-Reifen zulässig.

Zulässiges Gesamtgewicht des Zuges (mit Anhänger) maximal 2680 kg.

Wahlweise Anhängerkupplung laut EG-Typengenehmigung/Allgemeine Betriebserlaubnis

Mit vertiefter Bodengruppe hinten.

Mit Auffahrrampe im Fahrzeugheck.

Mit geänderter Anbaulage von Mittelschalldämpfer.

Mit geänderter Bodenverkleidung

Comment: WOW, TY so much sir! Now it makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

1. For S.1: optional 3 SEAT SERIES MAX 2 SINGLE SEATS For CHILDREN OF 15-36KG each
2. SEATS APPROVED ACCORDING TO ECE REGULATION NO. 44
  3.